# Cannot Embed a message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So have recently started looking into discord.py and I'm currently looking at embeds. It seems as though the code is not even running at all. Popped it into cmd and it runs fine.

```
@bot.command()
async def test(pass_context=True):
  embed = discord.Embed(title="CFA Pager", url="https://mazzanet.net.au/cfa/pager-cfa-all.php", description="v 0.0")
  embed.add_field(name=Type, value=type, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name=Location, value=location, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name=Description, value=description, inline=True)
  embed.set_footer(text="#1403903")
  await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `name = Type` to `name = "Type"`. Same thing with `Description` and `Location`. Where do you define the variables `type`, `description`, and `location` that you pass to keyword argument `value`?

Comment: type, description and location are not variables. They are are the values of name and value, preset vars for input into a embed. I got that part of the code form https://cog-creators.github.io/discord-embed-sandbox/ which i would imagine to be correct.

Comment: [According to the documentation they both need to be strings](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.add_field)

Comment: What error are you seeing when you try to invoke the command?

Comment: Check that the function is being called at all by having a print statement at the beginning and checking if it prints. If its not being called make sure that you have your bot prefix correctly set.

Answer (score 0):

```
  embed.add_field(name=Type, value=type, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name=Location, value=location, inline=False)
  embed.add_field(name=Description, value=description, inline=True)
```

You haven't defined the variables `type`, `location`, or `description` in the code you posted, so the command will throw `NameError`. Additionally, Python is looking for variables named `Type`, `Location`, and `Description` (case sensitive) for the `name` parameter in each call to `add_field` and can't find them.

If you wanted to use the literal values of `Type`, `Location`, and `Description` for the field names, you should do `embed.add_field(name="Type", value=value_of_type_field, inline=False)` (substituting different values for the different fields.)